# Database for Search Engine

Tags: database, search, search-engine, document-oriented-db, nosql

For research purposes, I have a need for a database system. I am building a search engine which uses two Inverted Index with millions of entries and an index containing simple key-value entries with the "values" containing the documents.

Everything is implemented in C++ and running on windows. It must also be open-source. So far, in dev I was loading everything in memory but since I'm now moving to bigger datasets, it's not possible.

I'm thinking of a document-oriented database. No need for big  functionalities since I will be making only simple Select and Insert however performance is an issue.

I'm open to any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ then you can try building it over [Xapian](https://xapian.org/).

Xapian is a highly adaptable toolkit which allows developers to easily add advanced indexing and search facilities to their own applications. It supports the Probabilistic Information Retrieval model and also supports a rich set of boolean query operators.